# Gettin a couldn't " Couldn't find Sheet with 'id'=" error when updating a sheet

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I'm getting an error when I try to update my "Sheet" here are the following files:

routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :sheets
  resources :userpage
  resources :users
  resources :index  

  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

  root 'index#new'
  get '/login' => 'sessions#new'
  post '/login' => 'sessions#create'
  get '/logout' => 'sessions#destroy'
  patch '/sheets' => 'sheets#edit'
  get '/signup' => 'users#new'
  post '/users' => 'users#create'
  get '/sheets' => 'sheets#index'
end
```

Comment: included it in the original question

Comment: it looks like all of the important information was deleted from your question, including the form markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you aren't passing an ID param to the `sheet_path`. Rails makes this easy for you, and allows you to pass the object. Rails will find the id and pass that param.

```
<%= link_to "Cancelar", sheet_path(@sheet) %>
```

Without using Rails's magic, you could write this explicitly as:

```
<%= link_to "Cancelar", sheet_path(id: @sheet.id) %>
```

If you're ever wondering what params a `_path` or `_url` helper requires, you can run `bundle exec rake routes` in the command line to get a list of all the routes and their required params. For example:

```
sheet GET     /sheets/:id      sheets#show
```

This tells you that you need to pass the `:id` param when using `sheet_path`.

Comment: I don't understand, could you explain better? this is my rake routes for sheets: 

`sheets GET    /sheets(.:format)            sheets#index
               POST   /sheets(.:format)            sheets#create
     new_sheet GET    /sheets/new(.:format)        sheets#new
    edit_sheet GET    /sheets/:id/edit(.:format)   sheets#edit
         sheet GET    /sheets/:id(.:format)        sheets#show
               PATCH  /sheets/:id(.:format)        sheets#update
               PUT    /sheets/:id(.:format)        sheets#update
               DELETE /sheets/:id(.:format)        sheets#destroy`

Comment: I think you misunderstood the problem, when I cancel it, it goes to the note just right, the problem is when I try to update or edit a note it gives me that error

Comment: @xdmanmagiconsei could you add the `form` partial markup to your question?

Comment: added form to the initial question